# PHP: make a new line on file_put_contents

Tags: php, html

I have trawled online looking for a working example, but I must be missing something, as it has been answered numerous times but I can't get it working.

I'm trying to send data ($file) to an html file. I can echo /print no bother but can't break a new line when sending to a html file via file_put_contents. I've tried "\r\n" with no success.

I'm using Chrome. This is the code I thought should work:

```
 $someData = $_POST['someData'];
 $file = 'file.html';

 file_put_contents($file, $someData . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: if you're viewing the HTML in the browser then newlines are not shown . You can instead use `<br/>` which is line break in HTML.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php#91793

Comment: How would I add the <br> though? I don't see the content sent by file_put_content on my mark up unless I F12 or check the content server side. I was hoping for an automatic line breaker that requires little attention.

Comment: Arkascha, I'm working my way through the manual and will post the solution when I find it. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML neither `CR`, `LF` nor `CRLF` matters really. That's why `<br />` tag exists and you need to use it instead or display your content in `<pre>` block or similar which is one of a few exceptions when `CR`/`LF` thing actually works as elsewhere.

Comment: where would I use the <br> though? If I use it in the form action mark up it doesnt have any effect. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

file_put_contents($file, $someData . PUT THE BREAK HERE IN INVERTED COMMAS . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

It was as simple as that on Chrome. I think I might have (gulp) forgotten to upload a file when i was trying this earlier.